# Question about fitness equipment migrated to sport where it was deemed to be closed as off topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closed-questions

My question about [stand-up paddles](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/will-beginner-notice-a-difference-between-lower-and-higher-middle-end-stand-up-p) was migrated to Sport, although [it was said](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/795/what-fitness-equipment-is-on-topic) that fitness equipment, including water sport equipment, is generally on topic.

I find it very problematic to migrate questions to sites, where they are obviously off topic (Sports is about professional/competitive sport, not training, not amateur sports).

Could you please clarify the on/off-topic status? Maybe water sport equipment should belong to Outdoors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I migrated the question, and in my head I meant to migrate it to Great Outdoors, which is where it resides now.

I considered whether to keep it or migrate it, and in the end I chose to migrate. While it is somewhat on topic here, I thought that it was more of a recommendation and I thought that Outdoors had a broader base of people that could potentially give it a good answer and attention.

The question wasn't really about using it in your program, it was more about the technical differences in the paddles, which was the tipping point for me to point it at a different site.